# Substituting variable values in a string

Tags: string, bash, variables, eval

I have a file (test.txt) with a line like this (verbatim):

```
MyCode $Cores
```

In a bash script, I have set the value of $Cores, so I want to execute the line from test.txt using this value. I tried this:

```
Cores=2
ProgramString=... read line from test.txt...
ProgramCommand=$(eval echo \$$ProgramString)
echo ${ProgramCommand}
${ProgramCommand}
```

The output is this:

```
$MyCode 2
```

It has successfully replaced $Cores with 2, but it has added a dollar sign at the beginning, so of course I get

```
$MyCode No such file or directory
```

Can anyone explain where this extra $ is coming from (and how to get rid of it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included the `$` with `\$`. Use `ProgramCommand=$(eval echo $ProgramString)` instead.

Comment: Wow, so easy... I thought the \$ was escaping the $ in my string. I see now that that was just inserting a $ to the beginning of the result, thanks.